# How do I get a post's page number?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have page which renders the featured image of a bunch of posts. I never render a single post. All cool.

However when people find a post through a search engine (and thus directly go to a single post), I want to redirect the visitor to the index page and show the image.

HOWEVER, and here's the tricky part. I want to redirect them to right paginated page where that post would've appeared when a visitor would've just skipped through pages. So not just **mypage.com** but **mypage.com/page/x** . How do I get the page number for a post where it WOULD have appeared when just normally browsing through the pages?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume:
 - You're using some sort of SQL database to store the images to produce the posts
 - You've got a database of image that have no static page numbers stored with the image
 - Your policy is to display the newest picture first (page 1), then the next newest (page 2)

One strategy would be to select a count of everything newer than your image in the database and that should give you the page number of your image.

```
select count(*) from images u1 inner join images u2 
where u1.image_id=XXX and u1.inserted_dt < u2.inserted_dt
```